# pandas : how to apply scipy.stats test on a groupby object ?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   1       2
0  P  214233
1  P  130435
2  P  258824
3  P   75488
4  C  101215
5  C  105793
6  C  101591
```

I want to perform a Wilcoxon rank-sum test for instance. Why the following command doesn't work ?

```
import scipy.stats as ss
df.groupby(1).apply(ss.ranksums)
```

I think it doesn't work because scipy doesn't recognize the group :

```
TypeError: ranksums() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How one can achieve this ? Without doing the groupby manually :

```
ss.ranksums(df[df[1]=="C"][2], df[df[1]=="P"][2])
```

And somehow same problem with ANOVA :

if the dataframe is like this :

```
   1       2
0  P  214233
1  P  130435
2  A  258824
3  A  75488
4  A  101215
5  C  105793
6  C  101591
```

But here the error is :

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works.

```
values_per_group = [col for col_name, col in df.groupby(1)[2]]
ss.ranksums(*values_per_group)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain a bit ?

Comment: @jrjc I added an answer with more explanation and a dict comprehension approach.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation for @innohead's method is that `scipy.stats` tests expects only values columns and `groupby` splits a `DataFrame` into `(group_name, DataFrame)` tuples. Given a group column `1` and a value column `2`, you can use list comprehension with a groupby object `df.groupby(1)`, extract only the value column `df.groupby(1)[2]` and then iterate through the groupby tuples keeping the values (`col`) and discarding the names(`col_names`).

Instead of using list comprehension, you could also keep the variable names attached to the values by using a dict comprehension:

```
values_per_group = {col_name:col for col_name, col in df.groupby(1)[2]}
ss.ranksums(*values_per_group.values())
```